# Jquery animate opacity on thumbnails except for the one selected

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-animate, thumbnails

I have a set of thumbnails that I want to reduce to 40% when another thumbnail is selected. The original thumbnail will remain at 100% opacity. I need to have a general release for the faded out thumbnails, so that a click anywhere on the page will bring the other thumbs back to 100% opacity.

Here is the demo: http://www.dumstr.com/sofeb11/stash/

Js:

```
$(function() {           
    $("div#fadeout .stashthumb").click(function () {             
            $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);   
    },          
    function () {      
            $("div#fadeout .stashthumb").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);       
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="fadeout" class="stasher">

     <div style="opacity: 1;" class="stashthumb">
     <span><a href="#"><img src="img/stash-01.jpg"></a></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your javascript to this (I think it's the behavior you want, you're question isn't 100% clear to me):

```
$(function() {           
    $("div#fadeout .stashthumb").click(function (event) {             
        $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);       
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300); 
        event.stopPropagation();     // don't fire the body click handler
    });

    // here's the "anywhere on the page" part you wanted
    $("body").click(function() {
        $("#fadeout .stashthumb").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
    });   
});
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I'd still personally use the class as the selector (and then use not() to remove the clicked item) rather than siblings in case a change of page structure stops it working in the future.

Comment: Personally, I would too. I was just keeping it as similar to the original as possible.

Comment: Works! Well done Tesserex. Any chance you could add a cursor:pointer to the body during the faded out event... I like to show the area as clickable.

Comment: Should just be able to add $(body).css('cursor', 'pointer'); to the thumbnail click event. Then $(body).css('cursor', ''); in the body click.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Digitlworld's answer

```
$("div#fadeout .stashthumb").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // This will stop the click bubbling up to the body
    $(this).removeClass('thumb40').addClass('thumb100');
    $('.stashthumb').not(this).removeClass('thumb100').addClass('thumb40');
});

$(body).click(function() {
    $('.stashthumb').removeClass('thumb40').addClass('thumb100');
});
```

Comment: I think Digitlworld was suggesting using toggleClass to get the fading effect, but otherwise it works.

Comment: Indeed I was. I mean, there are many many ways to do this, I'm sure, I just wanted to do a quick jQuery one.

Comment: Will that $(body).click solution work if they click another block element? I assume it relies on event bubbling?

Comment: It does rely on bubbling, so it will work as long as the other element doesn't have stopPropagation.

Comment: It'll work on anything that doesn't have it's own click event with stopPropagation called inside. Damn @Tesserex, beat me to it! :D

Comment: Thanks, this is solid as well, I just wanted to throw it quickly together for a demo, but I will reference this if I need to go further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a CSS class assigned to thumbnails for 40% opacity, another for 100% opacity.

When I want to fade all of them back in, I'd use a jQuery `$(".thumb40")` or something like that to select the faded ones and set their CSS class to `.thumb100` using the jQuery function for fading between classes. [jQuery toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/)

To fade all but the current one, use a similar jQuery, `.thumb100` but put check code to make sure the one you're changing to `.thumb40` isn't the one you're selecting.

As for the click away, I'm curious about that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your jQuery like this:

```
    $("div#fadeout .stashthumb").click(function (e) {
    $(".stashthumb").animate({opacity: 1},300);    
            $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);   
            e.stopPropagation();
    });
$("body #fadeout:not(.stashthumb)").click(function () {
    $(".stashthumb").animate({opacity: 1},300);
});
```

Here's  a working example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ngWz/1/)

Comment: That part works, but he also wants a click anywhere on the page to restore them all to 100%.

Comment: [Updated] Thanks this is very helpful in another way. I am also interested in having all of the thumbs snap back to 100% when you click outside of the thumbs themselves. Would that require an image overlay set to the container?

Comment: I'll modify the fiddle to include clicking elsewhere to restore opacity to 100%.